# Python Requests Libarary Removes some Characters in URL when Sending Request

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm testing a web application and I need to send some malformed HTTP requests.
When I set URL to:

`URL = https://www.example.com/test?`

When I intercept the Request in Burp Suite I see that it removes the **?** at the end.

The URL will be:
**https://www.example.com/test**

I need to send quotation mark and other things which will be removed by library.

Comment: If you're expecting the *requests* library to handle invalid URLs you'll need to think again

Answer (score 1):

A blank querystring is intentionally stripped. If you add some params (like `https://www.example.com/test?exampleParam=true` the querystring will not be stripped.

[Source](https://github.com/psf/requests/issues/2912)

Answer (score 0):

```
https://www.example.com/test?txt=hello
```

In Python requests, the above address is entered with **params**

```
import requests

x = requests.get('https://www.example.com/test', params={'txt': 'hello'})
print(x.status_code)
```

[Ishlatish bo'yicha qo'llanma](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_requests_get.asp)

Comment: Yeah I know but I wanna just quotation mark to be in path not anything else.